# Bad width, sections

Tags: html, css, uitableview, height, width

I have problem with sections and resolution.
When is width smaller and smaller sections are bugging together, ex. section home to section about.
I dont know what more i need to write to stop this problem.
What more i can write to fix sections without bugging or something.
There is screenshot for better view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/At7P3.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="home">
    <h1>Test</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!

</p>
  </section>

  <section class="about">
    <h1>Test</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!


  </section>

  <section class="contact">
    <h1>Test</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!


  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}


.home {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.about {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.contact {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In section change `100vh` with `100%`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


.home {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.about {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.contact {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="home">
    <h1>Test</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!

</p>
  </section>

  <section class="about">
    <h1>Test</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!


  </section>

  <section class="contact">
    <h1>Test</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis beatae facilis est, quod veniam amet sunt assumenda repudiandae, numquam error tenetur. Ducimus sit omnis recusandae similique ipsa? Eligendi, nulla tempora!


  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but i wanted 100vh bcs its on full page and with that i dont know how to fix that or what i need to change ? @Evren